# iOS: inserting iFrame with SRC inside the page immediately opens the url in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, iframe

I have quite a strange problem. This is happening inside a Cordova (hybrid HTML) app, but only on iOS.

I have my HTML page with some content already there, and that's ok.
In a second moment, I'm retrieving some HTML from a remote page and I insert this HTML inside my main HTML page. If there's an iFrame with an SRC attribute specified, the system immediately opens that SRC inside safari/a specific app, but I just want to insert the content as a normal iFrame!

Example. If I retrieve this HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">
```

and let's say that I save this HTML element inside a variable foo. As soon as i do:

```
document.getElementById("XXX").appendChild(foo);
```

iOS immediately opens the youtube app. No user interaction, no triggers, nothing. Just by inserting the iFrame in the page.
The same happens with any other SRC specified.

I tried to replace the "src" attribute with a fake one, like "data-src", insert the iFrame in the page and in a second moment put back the original SRC. As soon as I do that, the same stuff happens.

Do you have any idea on what is causing this and how to implement a workaround? On Android everything's fine.

P.S.: I'm using wkwebview, if that matters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it! Damn, if that was a stupid mistake!
In my config.xml I forgot to put this

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

This was blocking everything from being played inside my webview, and as a backup option, iOS was trying to open the iframe URL on another browser (such as Safari).

Thank you Erik anyway! I guess I wasted 50 bounty points :(